# JustTouched works on windows?

Tags: java, windows, libgdx

I'm using `justTouched` for manipulate easly touches and released in android, cause `isTouched` method acumulates many touches; but it works as the same in windows? Meaning, one event even when keep pressed? Or do I need another method/invoker/listener?

Comment: AFAIK it works the same, why don't you try to check it?, however see [doc](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html#justTouched--), the main obvious difference is that the touch screen is replaced by mouse input but it doesn't say anything about a different behavior...

Comment: Gracias, señor. But if i do this `if (Gdx.input.justTouched() || Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT))` Then `justTouched` works like `isTouched`. If I  put inside `touched++` And out of that if is called as `font.draw(batch, String.Valueof (touches), 100, 100);` then keep pressed and the touches keeps accumulated till release, if i quit/erase/comment `isButtonPressed` then touches only counts every press/release event, not while pressing. I just put it for working on windows, but haven't tested.

Comment: what you say is exactly what it should happend, what are you trying to do?

Comment: If `justTouched` works with windows, and counts 1 event till it's released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On desktop builds, Libgdx treats mouse button presses as touches. `justTouched` acts exactly the same, except that it polls mouse buttons instead of screen taps. And just like how on mobile you can't tell which finger just touched the screen, you can't tell which mouse button was just pressed. If you need to know which mouse button or finger touched down, you need to use an InputProcessor, which gives you far more information than using the Gdx.input convenience methods.

If you don't care which mouse button was just pressed, all you need is:

```
if (Gdx.input.justTouched()){
    //...
}
```

Based on your comments under your question, you seem to be trying to distinguish which button just touched with `|| Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT))` which will return true on every frame as long as the left button is held down. And if instead you did `&& Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT))`, then you wouldn't be sure that it's the left button that was just pressed. (Maybe you're holding down the left button and just pressed the right button.) There is no easy way to distinguish which button was pressed unless you are using an InputProcessor.

Comment: Think you answered my question, till the code you've written and before "Based....". Thank you